# Property 'id/name/duration/calories' does not exist on type 'unknown'

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

```
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
import { Exercise } from './../exercise.model';
import { TrainingService } from './../training.service';
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFirestore } from 'angularfire2/firestore';
import { Observable, Subscriber } from 'rxjs';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-new-training',
  templateUrl: './new-training.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./new-training.component.css'],
})
export class NewTrainingComponent implements OnInit {
  exercises: Observable<Exercise[]>;

  constructor(
    private trainingService: TrainingService,
    private db: AngularFirestore
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.exercises = this.db
      .collection('availableExercises')
      .snapshotChanges()
      .map((docArray) => {
        return docArray.map((doc) => {
          return {
            id: doc.payload.doc.data().id,
            name: doc.payload.doc.data().name,
            duration: doc.payload.doc.data().duration,
            calories: doc.payload.doc.data().calories,
          };
        });
      });
  }

  onStartTraining(form: NgForm) {
    this.trainingService.startExercise(form.value.exercise);
  }
}
```

Have issue with id, name, duration, and calories.. they are all underlined and error says: Property does not exist on type 'unknown' for all four. So not sure what the issue is. I have tried as well

```
id: doc.payload.doc['id'],
name: doc.payload.doc['name'],
duration: doc.payload.doc['duration'],
calories: doc.payload.doc['calories'],
```

doesn't work as well. Was repeating after Maximilian Schwarzmuller's tutorial. Would appriciate any help.

Comment: In the line `docArray.map((doc) => {` try adding `:any` like `docArray.map((doc: any) => {`

Comment: What is the behavior you're expecting instead of what you're seeing now?  Please edit the question to be clear what is not working the way you expect, and what you've done to debug it.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was to change the next line on the function `ngOnInit` from:

```
        return docArray.map((doc) => {
```

Into:

```
        return docArray.map((doc: any) => {
```

This will allow you to allow you to avoid type checking during compilation. As mentioned [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#any)